Issue when running a script in newest version of SoapUI (Version 5.7.2)
I was doing a task of compatibility testing.
There I had to run a script in SoapUI version 5.7.2, which is successfully running in the SoapUI version 5.5 and 5.2.
There I got an error when running the xlread.
Ex :
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script3.groovy: 11: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil 
 @ line 11, column 1.
   import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil; 
   ^

org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil @ line 11, column 1.
    at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1437)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:262)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.lambda$new$16(CompilationUnit.java:738)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$ISourceUnitOperation.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:901)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:627)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.doParseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:389)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.lambda$parseClass$3(GroovyClassLoader.java:332)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.compute(StampedCommonCache.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.memoize.StampedCommonCache.getAndPut(StampedCommonCache.java:154)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:330)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:526)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:538)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:570)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:565)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:136)
    at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:87)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:143)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:251)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831) 1 error

